# Custom gem is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am developing using Cloud9. I'm having an issue deploying a gem I have made onto Heroku. The gem itself will run locally, but when I attempt to deploy the app to Heroku I get this error.

[image]

My gem is a class so far as I can tell so I'm not sure of the issue.

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not an image.

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit the question but I will in the future

Answer (score 0):

Probably what happened is that u have syntax error like unfinished method call on line 3 u fixed in your computer but didnt commit it to repo and u pushing older repo to your heroku what has error unfixed.